# In AngularJS How to toggle between 2 checkboxes and get only 1 value

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, input

In AngularJS; How do I toggle between two checkboxes and get only one value

```
<td >
  <input type="checkbox" value="{{person.person_ID}}">{{person.home_address}}
</td>
<td >
  <input type="checkbox" value="{{person.person_ID}}">{{person.office_address}}
</td>
```

According to the requirement I have list of persons in that every person has two 
columns `home_address`  and `office_address`, I want to toggle between addresses and get only 1 
value like if person.home_address is checked than office_address should be unchecked and vice versa, and I want to get only 1 address like `"person.person_ID":home_address`

Comment: How about using radio buttons?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating it. Have you tried anything before asking? What didn't work, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Raghav i can't use radio button. because user can select any 1 at a time or nothing but not both.

Comment: Radio buttons are meant for selecting one or nothing but not both. Please provide a plunkr or fiddle so we can help with your code

Comment: Hi Patrick I tried but i am not getting how to get Checked value using ng-model and how to toggle using function in controller

Comment: @Arnold: Wait, in your post you state "user is only allowed to select one value", and in your comment you state "with radio buttons user cannot select both", would you please clarify your actual requirement. Regarding selecting none, you can set one as default and select that initially.

Comment: With a checkbox you can use `ng-model="variableInScope"` to bind your checkbox to a value in your scope, which you can then use in your controller.

Comment: Actual requirement:- Checkbox behavior 
both check boxes can not be selected in the row 
Both check boxes can be unselected in the row 
Either of one check box should be selected 
Header check boxes in both columns used for "select All"

Comment: Can you use three radio buttons in that case? "Select none", "Home Address", "Office address"?

Comment: I have json object like below  [{"person_ID":"p1","gotoA":"A","gotoB":"B"},
{"person_ID":"p2","gotoA":"A","gotoB":"B"}] which i am displaying as two checkbox i want get value like "person_ID":"A" or "person_ID":"B"

Comment: NO only two checkboxes i have to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-model to bind to a value in your person instance using the following html. (A [fiddle is available](http://jsfiddle.net/fz6jJ/))

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="person.option"
       value="{{person.person_ID}}"
       ng-true-value="'home'"
       ng-false-value="'none'">{{person.home_address}}
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="person.option"
       value="{{person.person_ID}}"
       ng-true-value="'office'"
       ng-false-value="'none'">{{person.office_address}}
```

here the checkboxes binds to the same variable `person.option` which is set depending on the value of the checkbox to the expression in ng-true-value and ng-false-value. By setting these to the some value other than that of the other we can either select none, or only one.

In your controller you can simply check person.option to get what checkbox is selected.

```
if (person.option === 'home') { }
else if (person.option === 'office') { }
```